# Javascript: select a value & redirect to page on pageload

Tags: javascript, html

```
<select onchange="formChanged(this);" NAME="country" id="first-disabled" class="selectpicker" >

    <OPTION VALUE="non-value">
    <OPTION VALUE="1.html" selected  id="test"> 1
    <OPTION VALUE="2.html"> 2
    <OPTION VALUE="3.html"> 3     

</select>

if (localStorage && localStorage.country) {
    location = localStorage.country;    
}


function formChanged(form) {
    var val = form.options[form.selectedIndex].value;
        if (val !== 'non-value') {
            if (localStorage) {
                localStorage.country = val;
            }
        location = val;
        }
}

function clear_me() {
    localStorage.clear();
}
```

From above code, How can i select `value 1` & redirect to `1.html` page on pageload?

I dont want user to select an option (Hidden from user).

I want to achieve on `pageload`.

I am totally new to javascript. Please help

Comment: So you are looking to load the site onto the page 1.html on initial load? If so what is need for the select box?

Comment: option menu for localstorage...so that when user come back it redirects it to same page or previous page.

Comment: I am still unsure of what you are looking to achieve, could you give more information about the desired out come. When does some one select from the option menu?

Comment: If you don’t want the user to choose, that means you always want to redirect to the same page? If so, what is this needed for at all then - why do you not send the user to the right destination page in the first place, what would this “intermediate” page be good for then? You really need to explain what you want to achieve here better.

Comment: see i am running a book reading website...what i want is user should redirect to same page where they were ended reading or last page of their visit. 

each page (ie.2.html) will have a buton with 

<button class="btn btn-red waves-button waves-effect waves-light" onclick="clear_three()">3</button>

<script>
function clear_three() {
    localStorage.clear();
 window.location.href = "3.html";
 }  
 
</script>

Comment: @A2zbollywood So basically you want people to return to the page that they left from before? So they can continue reading from where they stopped reading.

Comment: @Granny yes....

Comment: @A2zbollywood Are your users loggin in? If so you can upload the page url to the database with the userID so when they click 'close' the page gets uploaded and when they log back in and click on the book it grabs the page and loads it? Or do you want to use Localstorage for sure?

Comment: no users or login....I want to use Localstorage ...can u please help?